# Executing two asynctask instances in Android

Tags: android, crash, android-asynctask, conditional-statements, race-condition

I'm executing two asyntask instances, one of them in onCreate and the other one in onScroll handler. The intention of the app is to download via web-services X amount of information and when the scroll goes to the bottom, keep loading information. The information is well loaded, but sometimes, it keeps Loading and the app crashes.

Here is the doInBackground code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Declaro los parametros a enviar a la BD
        cargando=true;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //parametro enviado (ciudad)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ciudad", "5"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inicio", Integer.toString(inicio)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limite", Integer.toString(delante)));

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        String def="default";

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                if (primeraEjecucion){
                    String MAX = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    totalConsultas=Integer.parseInt(MAX);
                }

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    if (date.equals(def)){
                        //tratar la fecha
                    }
                    else{
                        boolean mostrarEvento=compararFechas(date);
                        if (mostrarEvento){
                            Evento e=new Evento();                                                      
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_POST_TITLE);
                            String post = c.getString(TAG_POST);
                            String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                            String place = c.getString(TAG_PLACE);
                            String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);

                            e.setID(Integer.parseInt(id));
                            e.setTitulo(name);
                            e.setPost(post);
                            e.setImagen(image);
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); 
                            Date fecha1 = sdf.parse(date , new ParsePosition(0));
                            e.setFecha(fecha1);
                            e.setLugar(place);
                            e.setCategoria(category);
                            eventos.add(e);                                                             
                        }                                               
                    }
                }
            }               
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;        
    }
```

On postExecute i'm updating the adapter. I've printed Logs and seems sometimes, the app tries to execute the asynctask onScroll a lot of times without touching the screen. I've protected the execution of the asynctask with a boolean.

Log:

```
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter 
has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. 
Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified 
from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. 
[in ListView(2131099648, class android.widget.ListView) 
with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1510)
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-22 16:53:06.662: E/AndroidRuntime(391):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
```

onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.all_products);
new LoadAllProducts().execute();
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
int elementoFinal=firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
if (inicio<=totalConsultas){
    if (elementoFinal==totalItemCount && !primeraEjecucion && !cargando){
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }
}else{
if (control){
    lv.removeFooterView(footerView);                    
control=false;
}

}
}
});
}
```

Comment: Show the code whre you execute this task.

Comment: Do you call notify days set changed after you update adapter that should be the second line after updating adapter

Comment: @PulkitSethi 
adapter.sort(comparador);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Your mistake is probably in sorting. You can't do operations on data set of list view you need to create a new sorted object, set this on list view and them call adapter methods.if you sort like this then during scrolling list view will try accessing data that has changed or changing causing exception

Comment: If you want to do operations on Adapter, create a deep copy of it Model data = adapter.DeepCopy(). then data.sort, adaptert.SetData(data), adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged(). All the above metohds you need to implement. This is required for changing data in a non UI (main) thread

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` each time you change its data.

Comment: I'm calling the adapter on postExecute(), right after changing data

Comment: The exception said the opposite.

Comment: I know, sometimes i get that exception, other times i get my app with a Dialog "Loading" all time without any exception

Comment: Are you sure you prevent well the 2 async tasks to modify the adapter  at the same time ?

Comment: i try to. I control the acces with a boolean

Comment: try to disable one async then the other to see if the problem still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `eventos` is the array you passed into the adapter, don't change it from doInBackground. Instead, you can set your AsyncTask to return the class Evento, which will pass it into onPostExecute. From there call `eventos.add(e)`, you need to change the contents of the adapter only on the main thread, which is where onPostExecute is ran.

Comment: eventos is an arraylist of my class Evento. I'm adding each Evento to the arrayList and then, in postExecute I create my class adapter passing to it eventos. Is that right or should i do it like you told me?

Comment: try adding it in onPostExecute. If two instances of this can be running, then you could have already passed eventos into the adapter when the second one is trying to change it.